# How can I discern the type of a program?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

When I do a matrix perception roll in the matrix I can discern if an icon is a program, a user, ... . What I did not see though is if I can discern with the same roll if a program is a normal program or an IC.

Thus my question here is: Does a matrix perception roll that discerns the type of the icon also tell you that? Or is there something else you can do (if something at all) to discern if a program is a normal program or an IC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You use your net hits to obtain additional information

A success simply means you found an *Icon*, but you can buy extra information about this icon with additional successes (page 241):

> **For each net hit scored, you can ask for one piece of information** about the object—***this could be type***, a rating, how many marks it has on it, any files it may be carrying, which grid it is using, whether any silent running icons are in the area, or any other pertinent Matrix information.

One of the informations you can obtain is the icon's *type*, and as we know, IC are a type of program:

> Intrusion countermeasures, or IC (pronounced “ice”), is a **type of program** that runs in hosts.

So, if you obtain at least 3 successes (2 net hits) on your Matrix Perception check, you could ask:

- What type of object is it? *"A program"*.
- What type of program? *"An IC"*.

Comment: tnx completely overlooked that. I really wish they would get it how to layout things so that you have the important parts in one part and not splitted up (like matrix perception) into 3-4 parts at different locations.

Comment: Matrix perception is actually *all over the place*. You have to ctrl+F the pdf to find what can be detected using it or not. Owning only a copy of the physical book might drive you crazy if you have to lookup certain rules.

Comment: luckily for me programmers are usually called crazy anyway :D

Comment: @ShadowKras -- you'd think it'd have this thing called an "index entry"...

Comment: @Shalvenay FASA, FanPro, and Catalyst are equally notorious for poor indexing over various editions of Shadowrun.